# Execution function just once when Express starts

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, boot

Which could be the best pattern to execute a function just once when ExpressJS start? Any idea? I haven't found anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

app.listen `callback` may be useful to you

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.listen

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    //some logic
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to listen to the event as opposed to passing the function as a callback when listen is invoked, you can do the following:

```
app.on('listening', function () {
    // server running and listening for requests

   // your code here
});
```

Or

```
app.on('listening', someFnToCall);
```